# KeyError 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' in waf on kubuntu

Tags: python, linux, waf, pycairo

I'm trying to install pycairo on kubuntu 13.04, and it's giving me an error complaining about MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET:

```
(virtualenv-3)naught101@naught101-chronos:/tmp/pycairo-1.10.0$ python waf configure
  ./options()
Setting top to                           : /tmp/pycairo-1.10.0 
Setting out to                           : /tmp/pycairo-1.10.0/build_directory 
  ./configure()
Checking for 'gcc' (c compiler)          : ok 
Checking for program python              : /home/naught101/.virtualenvs/virtualenv-3/bin/python 
Checking for python version              : (3, 3, 2, 'final', 0) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/pycairo-1.10.0/.waf3-1.6.4-e3c1e08604b18a10567cfcd2d02eb6e6/waflib/Scripting.py", line 93, in waf_entry_point
    run_commands()
  File "/tmp/pycairo-1.10.0/.waf3-1.6.4-e3c1e08604b18a10567cfcd2d02eb6e6/waflib/Scripting.py", line 145, in run_commands
    run_command(cmd_name)
  File "/tmp/pycairo-1.10.0/.waf3-1.6.4-e3c1e08604b18a10567cfcd2d02eb6e6/waflib/Scripting.py", line 138, in run_command
    ctx.execute()
  File "/tmp/pycairo-1.10.0/.waf3-1.6.4-e3c1e08604b18a10567cfcd2d02eb6e6/waflib/Configure.py", line 124, in execute
    super(ConfigurationContext,self).execute()
  File "/tmp/pycairo-1.10.0/.waf3-1.6.4-e3c1e08604b18a10567cfcd2d02eb6e6/waflib/Context.py", line 87, in execute
    self.recurse([os.path.dirname(g_module.root_path)])
  File "/tmp/pycairo-1.10.0/.waf3-1.6.4-e3c1e08604b18a10567cfcd2d02eb6e6/waflib/Context.py", line 127, in recurse
    user_function(self)
  File "/tmp/pycairo-1.10.0/wscript", line 29, in configure
    ctx.check_python_headers()
  File "/tmp/pycairo-1.10.0/.waf3-1.6.4-e3c1e08604b18a10567cfcd2d02eb6e6/waflib/Configure.py", line 217, in fun
    return f(*k,**kw)
  File "/tmp/pycairo-1.10.0/.waf3-1.6.4-e3c1e08604b18a10567cfcd2d02eb6e6/waflib/Tools/python.py", line 131, in check_python_headers
    if dct[x]:
KeyError: 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
(virtualenv-3)naught101@naught101-chronos:/tmp/pycairo-1.10.0$
```

Of course, I'm not on a Mac, so I have no idea why this is appearing. Any ideas?

Edit: `build_directory/config.log`:

```
# project pycairo (1.10.0) configured on Fri Oct  4 20:15:40 2013 by
# waf 1.6.4 (abi 98, python 30302f0 on linux)
# using waf configure
#
----------------------------------------
Setting top to
/tmp/pycairo-1.10.0
----------------------------------------
Setting out to
/tmp/pycairo-1.10.0/build_directory
----------------------------------------
Checking for 'gcc' (c compiler)
find program=['gcc', 'cc'] paths=['/home/naught101/.virtualenvs/virtualenv-3/bin', '/home/naught101/.pyenv/shims', '/home/naught101/.pyenv/bin', '~/bin', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin', '/home/naught101/bin', '/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm', '/usr/local/sbin', '/usr/local/bin', '/usr/sbin', '/usr/bin', '/sbin', '/bin', '/usr/games', '/usr/local/games', '/usr/brlcad/bin'] var='CC' -> '/usr/bin/gcc'
find program=['ar'] paths=['/home/naught101/.virtualenvs/virtualenv-3/bin', '/home/naught101/.pyenv/shims', '/home/naught101/.pyenv/bin', '~/bin', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin', '/home/naught101/bin', '/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm', '/usr/local/sbin', '/usr/local/bin', '/usr/sbin', '/usr/bin', '/sbin', '/bin', '/usr/games', '/usr/local/games', '/usr/brlcad/bin'] var='AR' -> '/usr/bin/ar'
ok
----------------------------------------
Checking for program python
/home/naught101/.virtualenvs/virtualenv-3/bin/python
find program=['python'] paths=['/home/naught101/.virtualenvs/virtualenv-3/bin', '/home/naught101/.pyenv/shims', '/home/naught101/.pyenv/bin', '~/bin', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin', '/home/naught101/bin', '/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm', '/usr/local/sbin', '/usr/local/bin', '/usr/sbin', '/usr/bin', '/sbin', '/bin', '/usr/games', '/usr/local/games', '/usr/brlcad/bin'] var='PYTHON' -> '/home/naught101/.virtualenvs/virtualenv-3/bin/python'
['/home/naught101/.virtualenvs/virtualenv-3/bin/python', '-c', 'import sys\nfor x in sys.version_info: print(str(x))']
out: 3
3
2
final
0

['/home/naught101/.virtualenvs/virtualenv-3/bin/python', '-c', "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib\n\nprint(repr(get_python_lib(standard_lib=0, prefix='/usr/local') or ''))"]
out: '/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages'

['/home/naught101/.virtualenvs/virtualenv-3/bin/python', '-c', "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib\n\nprint(repr(get_python_lib(plat_specific=1, standard_lib=0, prefix='/usr/local') or ''))"]
out: '/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages'

----------------------------------------
Checking for python version
(3, 3, 2, 'final', 0)
['/home/naught101/.virtualenvs/virtualenv-3/bin/python', '-c', "from distutils.sysconfig import get_config_var\n\nprint(repr(get_config_var('prefix') or ''))\nprint(repr(get_config_var('SO') or ''))\nprint(repr(get_config_var('LDFLAGS') or ''))\nprint(repr(get_config_var('LIBDIR') or ''))\nprint(repr(get_config_var('LIBPL') or ''))\nprint(repr(get_config_var('INCLUDEPY') or ''))\nprint(repr(get_config_var('Py_ENABLE_SHARED') or ''))\nprint(repr(get_config_var('MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET') or ''))\nprint(repr(get_config_var('LDSHARED') or ''))\nprint(repr(get_config_var('CFLAGS') or ''))"]
out: '/home/naught101/.virtualenvs/virtualenv-3'
'.so'
"-L'/home/naught101/.pyenv/versions/3.3.2/lib'"
'/home/naught101/.pyenv/versions/3.3.2/lib'
'/home/naught101/.pyenv/versions/3.3.2/lib/python3.3/config-3.3m'
'/home/naught101/.pyenv/versions/3.3.2/include/python3.3m'
''
''
"gcc -pthread -shared -L'/home/naught101/.pyenv/versions/3.3.2/lib'"
'-Wno-unused-result -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes'

Configuration returned from ['/home/naught101/.virtualenvs/virtualenv-3/bin/python']:
"prefix = '/home/naught101/.virtualenvs/virtualenv-3'\nSO = '.so'"
```

Comment: `waf` usually leaves a log file named `config.log` in the build directory. If it did, can you upload it to pastebin or somewhere similar and add a link?

Comment: Meanwhile, the most likely cause seems to be a problem with your Python configuration. How did you install your Python? What does `import sysconfig, distutils.sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_config_var('MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_HEADER')); print(distutils.sysconfig.get_config_var('MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_HEADER'))` say?

Comment: Oh, and since you're using a virtualenv, was that migrated from another machine, or built from scratch?

Comment: There is no log file after the error. If I run that code in python, I get `None; None;`. I built the virtualenv using pyenv on this machine, and I'm using virtualenvwrapper to use it.

Comment: You're sure there's no `config.log` in `build_directory`?

Comment: Ah, yes, there is. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: OK, so at the earlier stage in the configure, it's successfully checking for `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` and finding `''`, as it should… so I have no idea why it's failing to look up the same thing later. It probably has something to do with how that `dct` gets built out of the config vars, but I can't think of anything obvious, and I don't want to read and debug that much code. Hopefully someone else has a clue.